# Corda — Share subset of states with counterparty using FilteredTransaction

Tags: corda

Currently, if I want to share some state with the counterparty I have several options:

1. Provide session in FinalityFlow
2. Explicitly start **SendSignedTransactionFlow**
3. Explicitly start **SendStateAndRefFlow**

Let's assume that I have a notarized SignedTransaction which produces 10 states.

Questions:

1. Am I able to share only 5 states with some non-signing participant?
2. May I send a **FilteredTransaction** and force the counterparty to store states that FilteredTransaction contains?

Answer (score 1):

To address your first question: Yes, you are able to share part of your signedTransaction to the counterparty (based on filtering) More details can be found @https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-tear-offs.html

To address your second question: You cannot actually force to store states to any node. What kind of data the Ledger gets store would be agreed during the Cordapp design.

Comment: According to: `ResolveTransactionsFlow` (which is part of SendSignedTransactionFlow) code I can force to store ALL states of the transaction or ALL_VISIBLE using `StatesToRecord` parameter.
https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/e35c0c1df74e9c475afc31ec7750b11c88bc4742/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/internal/ResolveTransactionsFlow.kt#L18